# I am having trouble testing my angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to learn testing and I am having a lot of issues right now.

Here is my very basic component:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("testList", [])
    .component("testList", {
      templateUrl: "test-list.component.html",
      controllerAs: "model",
      controller: testController
    });

  function testController() {
    var model = this;
    model.test = "test";
  }
}());
```

All I am trying to do in my test is to make sure that "test" equals "test", but I am getting the following error in my console: `undefined is not a function`

```
"use strict";

describe("Testing Component", function () {
  var $componentController;

  beforeEach(module('testList'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
  }));

  it("should see if test equals test", function() {
    var ctrl = $componentController('testList', null, { test: "test"});
    expect(ctrl.test).toEqual("test");
  });
});
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong there. Here's a JSBin with (more or less) exactly your code: https://jsbin.com/cefefabobo/edit?html,js,output. The test passes.

Perhaps you haven't loaded the `angular-mocks.js` script correctly?